# Laravel - how to check if a conversation exist between 2 users - messaging system

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have a messaging system, but i fail to check if a conversation exist between two users, so every time a user tries to message a user, a new Conversation is created.

Googling I tried some code like this one:

```php
$hasConversation = Conversation::whereHas('receiver', function ($query) use ($userIds) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $userIds);
})->count() === 2;
```

Without success.

I wonder if there is an easy way to check before create a new Conversation.

Conversations DB: 
 - sender_id
 - receiver_id
 - is_seen
 - is_locked

Messages DB: 
 - message
 - user_id (I don't know, maybe it's not even needed)
 - conversation_id

Models:

User:

```php
public function received()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Conversation', 'receiver_id');
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
}


public function sent()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Conversation', 'sender_id');
}
```

Conversation:

```php
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}

public function sender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function receiver()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: your schema seems incomplete, or am I missing something?

Comment: Hm, thats all in the schema

Comment: why do you do `count() === 2`?

Comment: Saw some answer that i tough might help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to query the conversation row directly. Using `whereHas` probably won't work as well when it needs to cross between 2 relationships.

```php
$existingConversation = Conversation::where([
 [ 'sender_id', '=', $userIds[0] ],
 [ 'receiver_id', '=', $userIds[1] ] 
])->orWhere([
 [ 'sender_id', '=', $userIds[1] ],
 [ 'receiver_id', '=', $userIds[0] ] 
])->first();
```

This *should* get the first existing conversation between the two users.